# The right delegate - ImageMagick

Tags: delegates, imagemagick

Ubuntu Server 17.04 + ImageMagick 7-0-6 ImageMagick

There are a lot of SONY RAW (*.ARW) files in the declared delegates in **delegates.xml**

> ... delegate decode="arw" command=""/opt/alfresco/scripts/arw2jpg.sh"
>   "%i" "%o""/
>
> delegate decode="dng:decode" command=""ufraw-batch" --silent
>   --create-id=also --out-type=png --out-depth=16 "--output=%u.png" "%i"" ...

coder.xml - no changes

arw2jpg.sh - custom script that use DCRAW to extract embedded JPG from ARW (dcraw -e ...). Script itself is working correctly.

The question - during CONVERT job, ImageMagick always chooses the **dng:decode** delegate instead of **arw**?

Can somebody help me to define the right delegates order for ImageMagick?

Comment: Question probably is better off on the [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) stackexchange site.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to ensure the custom delegate protocol is specified during usage.

For example..

```
convert arw:input_file.arw output.jpg
```

> Why?

ImageMagick chooses delegates by magick-header/number, and if it's unable to find the delegate, it'll evaluate matching file extensions. In your example, you simply have competing delegates, and the conflict resolution/priority is not to your favor. You have to be explicit about which delegate to use (i.e. `arw:`).

Comment: Thanks ! Cleare - but CONVERT is generated by Alfresco CE and I can't add ARW: prefix

Comment: Even when specifying the delegate protocol, I'm still getting an error:

```
convert-im6.q16: delegate failed `'ufraw-batch' --silent --create-id=also --out-type=png --out-depth=16 --output='%u.png' '%i'' @ error/delegate.c/InvokeDelegate/1966.
convert-im6.q16: unable to open image `/tmp/magick-7KwgaeDRK9w6xKh1eb9VsHiz4lm6DjAz.ppm': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2924.
```

This is the command I ran: convert arw:input/A7R-1.ARW metadata_image.jpg -append  arw:input/A7R-1.ARW

Answer (score 1):

Eric's (@emcconville) answer is the correct, sane way to do this, but you appear to be stuck between a rock and a hard place, so here's a slightly mad way to do it.

If **ImageMagick** always chooses the `DNG` delegate and you have no way to override this, you could force its hand by changing the `DNG` delegate to choose the way you want. So, you would change the existing `DNG` line so it looks like this:

```
delegate decode="dng:decode" command=""YourDecider" " "%i" "%o" "%u"
```

Then you write a script in `/usr/local/bin` that looks at the file extension and either calls `/opt/alfresco/scripts/arw2jpg.sh` with the appropriate parameters, or calls `ufraw-batch` with the same set of parameters that were originally in `delegates.xml`, i.e. `--silent --create-id=also --out-type=png --out-depth=16...`

So, your script `/usr/local/bin/YourDecider` would look something like this - COMPLETELY UNTESTED - just to give you an idea:

```
#!/bin/bash
################################################################################
# YourDecider
# Choose between decoding file with arw2jpg or ufraw-batch
################################################################################
in=$1
out=$2
unique=$3
ext=$(tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]" <<< "${in##*.}") 
if [ "$ext" = "arw" ]; then
   exec /opt/alfresco/scripts/arw2jpg.sh "$in" "$out"
else
   exec ufraw-batch --silent --create-id=also --out-type=png --out-depth=16 --output="${unique}.png" "$in" ...
fi
```

You would have to make it executable with:

```
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/YourDecider
```